# Testing approach for AngularJS Java Spring Project

Tags: eclipse, spring, angularjs, testing

Sorry for the general question, but what is the best approach/tools for testing an AngularJS project with Spring JPA and Restful services backend, I am using Eclipse.

Do you do the angularJS testing using tools external to Eclipse such as node.js, testacular etc...is there a way to do unit and end to end testing for the front JS end and the backen all inside Eclipse?

Regards

I

Comment: I kind of doubt it. You could probably install node/npm and grunt and just setup eclipse to run the external commands, but it would not be very integrated.

Comment: Thanks, so whats the normal approach, perform angular testing externally and separately and use maven to run unit tests agaisnt your services/model?

Comment: Pretty much. I work on both the UI and the backend services at my job and I just treat them as completely separate projects. I unit test the front end with grunt/karma/jasmine, and yeah we run the unit tests locally in eclipse for the services (with maven).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout $httpBackend in ngMock. You could set up a dedicated backend for testing, but if you're sure of the correct responses (just grab them via postman or something), $httpBackend is very simple to implement. We've been using it to develop a frontend asynchronously with a jersey backend, but it has testing functionality built in. Then you just need to set up seperate unit tests for your java and you'll be good to go.